# What syntax I should use to declare externs for closure compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I want to declare some externs for closure compiler but not know how to do it?

```
(function(window) {
window.myapi = window.myapi || {};

var myapi = window.myapi;

myapi.hello = function() {
  window.document.write('Hello');
}
}(window));
```

I am not sure how to do it for window.myapi, window.myapi.hello?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Externs are valid javascript, but they are just type information. They should not contain definitions (or for functions only empty definitions).

Here's a start: [How to Write Closure-compiler Extern Files Part 1](http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2013/09/12/how-to-write-closure-compiler-extern-files-part-1-the-basics/)

A couple of notes on your specific example:

1. Don't use an anonymous wrapper. Type names must be global.
2. Properties on the window object are the same as the namespace examples.
3. Functions shouldn't have implementations

Here's a corrected example:

```
/** @const */
window.myapi = {};

/** @return {undefined} */
window.myapi.hello = function() {};
```

In Closure-compiler properties on the `window` (global) object are seen completely differently than global variables. If you need both, you'll have to declare everything twice.

```
/** @const */
var myapi = {};

/** @return {undefined} */
myapi.hello = function() {};
```

Comment: I have some problem since syntax: var x = {}; not declare window.x and I need declare window.x = {};

Comment: Problem is that I must use anonymous wrapper because I do not want pollute or be polluted global scope at all. Thank for explanation that I need twice window.namespace and namespace declaration. I prefer control over syntax so will use long syntax window but very safe.